# T-SQL query to return most common emailAddress (2 Table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hey all I have the following two tables and the question below.

Tables:

Students:

```
StudentID
Email
LastIPAdress
UserName
```

StudentCourses:

```
StudentCoursesID
StudentID
CourseID
```

The question is 
Create a T-SQL query to return the most common EmailAddress in the Users table.
I am assuming the most common EmailAddress is talking about the "Email Column"
And here is what query i tried to create.

```
Select Email, Count(StudentID) As student_value
FROM Students
Where StudentID = 1
Group by StudentD
Order BY student_value DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Would be glad if someone could explain how to approach this question.
Thanks

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax to me. Are you actually using sql-server (T-SQL) or not?

Comment: We are meant to be learning T-SQL. However i did also learn a little MySQL in my own time.
So i am sorry that i mixed them up i will re-look over my query thank you.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties? Why have you told us about the `StudentCourses` table? Where is the `Users` table you want the `EmailAddress` from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
Select TOP 1 Email, Count(*) As student_value
FROM Students
Group by Email
Order BY Count(*) DESC
```